# Spell checker with Bjspell

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources

Did any one tested spell checker in visualforce page with [BJSpell](https://code.google.com/p/bjspell/) .I have included the bjspell.js file in static resource and included the script in vf page with apex:includescript  but still spell checker is not working.Any help is appreciated.

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="Coaching_Report__c" extensions="newFExtension" > 
     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.SpellChecker}"/> 
     <apex:form> 
          <apex:pageblock> 
               <apex:pageBlockSection title="Areas for Development" columns="1"> 
                    <apex:inputField value="{!newFCR.Development_Areas__c}" style="width: 100%;"/>
               </apex:pageblocksection> 
          </apex:pageblock> 
     </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Could you please post your VF and JS code so we can try to help identify the issue

Comment: Do you see any error messages in your browser's console?

Comment: @ Mike Chale I don't see any error message on my browser console

Comment: It's going to be very difficult for anyone to help or diagnose the issue without and code.  And perhaps some more description of 'not working'.

Comment: Please post the code and the screenshots of the browser console.

Comment: <apex:page Standardcontroller="Coaching_Report__c" extensions="newFExtension" >
<apex:form>
 <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.SpellChecker}"/>
 <apex:pageblock>
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Areas for Development" columns="1">
 <apex:inputField value="{!newFCR.Development_Areas__c}" style="width: 100%;"/>
 </apex:pageblocksection>
 </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/bjspell/downloads/detail?name=BJSpell.js

Comment: I have added the code to the question.  Where is your JS code to call the Spell checker?

Comment: I have created new static resource called spellchecker and uploaded the bjspell.js file to it.      
code.google.com/p/bjspell/downloads/detail?name=BJSpell.js

Comment: Do you see the file getting loaded by your browser? Does the generated HTML look correct?

Comment: yes, the file got loaded by browser and HTML looks correct

Comment: can someone help me please